Apache configuration to host both PHP and Python backend together not working for special Alias requirement
I am working on a web application in Ubuntu.
I have a PHP backend that I want to host in "http://localhost/myapp/".
All the application files are in the "/var/www/html/myapp/website/public/" folder. I also have a python backend. It is the API backend for the same application.
The python DRF project files reside in the "/var/www/html/myapp/api/v1/" folder. I need to host the DRF APIs in "http://localhost/myapp/v1/". I created the "/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.conf" file to configure my app in apache. But since "/myapp/v1/" has "/myapp/" in it, the php configuration is superseding and the WSGI is not working. If I remove the "Alias /myapp/", then the WSGI backend works fine in "http://localhost/myapp/v1/".
Below is my configuration I tried. What am I missing here? Thank you for your help.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    # WSGI handler for /myapp/v1/
    WSGIDaemonProcess myapi python-home=/opt/venv/myapp-python python-path=/var/www/html/myapp/api/v1/
    WSGIProcessGroup myapi
    WSGIScriptAlias /myapp/v1/ /var/www/html/myapp/api/v1/v1/wsgi.py process-group=myapi application-group=%{GL>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myapp/website/public/
    # PHP backend
    Alias /myapp/ /var/www/html/myapp/website/public/
    <Directory /var/www/html/myapp/website/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

